# order by asc but when the value 0 places in the last in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, sql-order-by

Here is my order by code

`$this->db->order_by('diskon', 'asc')`;

diskon is a number by the way. i want places the diskon that have 0 value in the last.
so it must be like this

```
1
2
4
6
0
```

hope you understand what i mean, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
order by (diskon > 0) desc, diskon asc
```